# One way of prepending html with jquery works but why the other way doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepend

This way of prepending does work for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#learn-more-button").click(function() {
                $("#main-text").load('ajax/learn-more.html #learn-more', function() {
                                            $(this).prepend('<p> DARN </p>'); // <=== This here WORKS
                    $(this).hide().fadeIn(500); //Fade in
                    $("#main-text").animate({ // Then Animate
                        width:"500px",
                        left:'+=400px',}, 
                        400
                    );                                                                  
                });                 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This way of prepending doesn't work for me:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#learn-more-button").click(function() {
                $("#main-text").prepend('<p> DARN </p>'); // <=== This here doesn't work
                $("#main-text").load('ajax/learn-more.html #learn-more', function() {
                    $(this).hide().fadeIn(500); //Fade in
                    $("#main-text").animate({ // Then Animate
                        width:"500px",
                        left:'+=400px',}, 
                        400
                    );                                                                  
                });                 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Why the second way doesn't work? How should it be done to make it work?

I'm not really a jQuery guy, so help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'doesn't work'? How doesn't it work? Do you get an error? Does it add the `<p>` element in the wrong place? Also, can you include the HTML that this jQuery works on in the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you perform the `load()` the contents of the `#main-text` element are completely replaced. Therefore if you add the `<p>DARN</p>` before the `load` - as in the second method, it gets overwritten.

In the first method the `<p>` is being added in the callback function of the load. This is called after the load has been completed.

You should also chain methods on to one selector for better performance, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#learn-more-button").click(function() {
            $("#main-text").load('ajax/learn-more.html #learn-more', function() {
                $(this).prepend('<p> DARN </p>')
                    .hide().fadeIn(500)
                    .animate({
                        width:"500px",
                        left:'+=400px'
                    }, 400);
            });                 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So it *is* being added, and then being replaced.